# Updating joined table associated with order... keeps creating instead of updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Situation:**

An order is created by ordercontroller create method into a orders table.

Then a video is uploaded by videoordercontroller create method into the videoorder table associated with the order_id.

I have this in the orders show page to upload the video to the order:

```
<%= form_for([@order, @video_order]) do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :video %>
<%= form.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
```

This form technically disapears after submission but i am testing updating the video because i also want to give the ability to update the video in case a wrong video is uploaded.

I tried:

```
<%= form_for([@order, @video_order], :url => edit_order_video_order_path(@order.id, @video_order), remote: true ) do |form| %>
   <%= form.file_field :video %>
 <%= form.submit "Upload", class: "btn btn-success"  %>
```

But this gives me the

```
"(No route matches [POST] "/orders/150/video_orders/150/edit")"
```

Which, of course this wouldn't work but i also can't figure out how to allow to update the video tables order_id from the same URL page.  I don't want to send the user to a new page for convenience.

So basically, how can i allow updating the orders video in the video table?

**Here's the models:**
video_order model

```
belongs_to :order
validates :order_id, uniqueness: true
```

order order model

```
has_one :video_order
```

The video_order model has the order_id and video only.
the order model doesn't have a video_id column.

Also, if you see any associations being wrong or have better ways, feel free to let me know.

Rake:

```
edit_order_video_order GET    /orders/:order_id/video_orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                        video_orders#edit

PATCH  /orders/:order_id/video_orders/:id(.:format)                                             video_orders#update
PUT    /orders/:order_id/video_orders/:id(.:format)                                             video_orders#update
```

This is taking place in the Order show page

I have this method in the order controller:

```
def show
    @user = current_user
    @video_order = VideoOrder.new
end
```

This where the uploading of the video takes place.  i also want to allow updating from it with a seprate form

Comment: Can you show routes defined ? Edit call must go on `put` or `patch` but it is going for `post`

Comment: just updated and added the edit and update routes... video_orders is nested under orders

Comment: I have tried attempts along the lines of "form_for([@order, @video_order], :method => :post, remote: true )" but nothing like it works... i would assume for that to work i would need to add the video_id to the orders table... but there is a way to not need that

Comment: Routes look proper, @video_order passed in form must be existing record with id for edit, is it new record ?

Comment: I have the record first created with the form in the OP.  so its there.  but i in the video_order table, i have order_id ... but no video_id in the order table.... but i should be able to update the video_order table from that same page, some how.  any ideas?

Comment: Do not get confused, simply check @video_order is having id or not.

Comment: yea it does have the id for it

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` method has a `options` parameter, you can set the form method as 'patch' as follows:

```
form_for @object, url: 'some_url', method: 'patch'
```

Comment: Thanks but how can i apply this to the situation at hand? i tried "<%= form_for([@order, @video_order], url: 'order_video_order', method: 'patch')  do |form| %>" and got "param is missing or the value is empty: order" which it looks like its trying to update from the ordercontroller instead of the associated video_ordercontroller

Comment: @uno Try to use the original URL: `:url => edit_order_video_order_path(@order.id, @video_order)`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works for updating the table and not creating a new row:

```
<%= form_for(@order.video_order)  do |form| %>
```

Only issue I'm currently having is the redirect after.  I get "Cannot redirect to nil!" but i will figure that out soon enough.

Redirect needed to be along the lines of this:

```
redirect_to order_path(@video_order.order_id)
```

In orde to redirect back to the order show page

This solution ended up being so simple! :)